# Classifying 1 cycle permutation matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, permutations

Given a permutation matrix that is not full rank, is there an algebraic criterion to tell if matrix contains more than one disjoint non-trivial cycle or exactly one non-trivial cycle?

Example:
Consider 
$$\begin{pmatrix}
0& 0& 0& 0& 1& 0& 0& 0\\
1& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0\\
0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0\\
0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0\\
0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 1\\
0& 1& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0\\
0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0\\
0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 1& 0& 0
\end{pmatrix}$$

This matrix embeds 1st row->2nd row->6th row->8th row->5th row->1st row cycle (essentially a 5-cycle in $8\times 8$ matrix).

When previous example acts on left on
\begin{pmatrix}
a1& a2& a3& a4& a5& a6& a7& a8\\
 b1& b2& b3& b4& b5& b6& b7& b8\\
 c1& c2& c3& c4& c5& c6& c7& c8\\
 d1& d2& d3& d4& d5& d6& d7& d8\\
 e1& e2& e3& e4& e5& e6& e7& e8\\
 f1& f2& f3& f4& f5& f6& f7& f8\\
 g1& g2& g3& g4& g5& g6& g7& g8\\
 h1& h2& h3& h4& h5& h6& h7& h8
\end{pmatrix}

we get
\begin{pmatrix}
e1& e2& e3& e4& e5& e6& e7& e8\\
 a1& a2& a3& a4& a5& a6& a7& a8\\
 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0\\
 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0\\
 h1& h2& h3& h4& h5& h6& h7& h8\\
 b1& b2& b3& b4& b5& b6& b7& b8\\
 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0\\
 f1& f2& f3& f4& f5& f6& f7& f8
\end{pmatrix}

Acting on left $5$ times gives\begin{pmatrix}
 a1& a2& a3& a4& a5& a6& a7& a8\\
 b1& b2& b3& b4& b5& b6& b7& b8\\
 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0\\
 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0\\
 e1& e2& e3& e4& e5& e6& e7& e8\\
 f1& f2& f3& f4& f5& f6& f7& f8\\
 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0\\
 h1& h2& h3& h4& h5& h6& h7& h8
\end{pmatrix}

Comment: For instance, you can tell by the characteristic polynomial.

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** The below answers an older version of the question, which has since been changed.

---

If $P$ is a permutation matrix, it will be exactly one cycle if and only if its characteristic polynomial is $x^n - 1$.

Here's a way to verify the characteristic polynomial without actually computing the associated determinant: first, verify that $P^n = I$.  Then, verify that $q(P) \neq 0$ for any polynomial $q$ that divides $(x^n - 1)/(x-1)$.  If this is the case, then $P$ consists of exactly one cycle.

---

In any example like that you've presented, we can compute $P^TP$ to get a diagonal matrix consisting of $1$s and $0$s.  If we consider the submatrix obtained by deleting all rows and columns corresponding to a diagonal zero, we obtain the smaller corresponding permutation of full rank.

In your example, we compute
$$
P^TP = 
\pmatrix{
1\\
&1\\
&&0\\
&&&0\\
&&&&1\\
&&&&&1\\
&&&&&&0\\
&&&&&&&1
}
$$
And get the submatrix
$$
\pmatrix{
0& 0&       1& 0&    0\\
1& 0&       0& 0&    0\\
%
%
0& 0&       0& 0&    1\\
0& 1&       0& 0&    0\\
%
0& 0&       0& 1&    0
}
$$

Comment: Why is $q(P)\neq0$ if $q|\frac{x^n-1}{x-1}$? In above matrix, if (3,3),(4,4),(7,7) entry is 1, we get 1 cycle. Mathematica does not give form you suggest. I am also  interested in situation where $P$ is not full rank as in example above.

Comment: I cannot delete rows. I understand what you are saying. But char poly on mathematica does not look way you suggest if cycle is not over $n$ letters. cycle could be over $m<n$ letters. Still we could have just 1 non trivial cycle (rest of letters be fixed).

Comment: What do you mean you can't delete rows?  Would it be better if we expressed row-deletion as a matrix operation?

Comment: @Turbo you never said "one *non-trivial* cycle" earlier.  That changes things drastically.

Comment: ahhhh ok I will update.